# Sphinx is caching python module somewhere: WHERE?

Tags: caching, python-sphinx

I am trying to use Sphinx to create simple documentation for a python module.  The first time I ran it, it worked fine.  Now I have made some updates to the module, and rerunning the documentation commands:

`$ sphinx-apidoc -P -F -f -e -o . /path/to/module
$ make html`

it *always* uses the old version of the python module code.  I have tried deleting the entire docs directory, moving the module, rechecking it out, updating sphinx - nothing works.

The old code is still being reused and cached somewhere.  It is driving me absolutely insane.

Answer (score 0):

Because Sphinx *imports* the module, it does not seem to find the local copy, but rather imports the older version already installed on my system, and uses that to generate the docs. Running `python setup.py install`, and *then* regenerating everything finally worked.

Comment: Have you tried using [tox](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tox)? We use it for projects under the Pylons Project for running tests under multiple versions of Python and building docs. For example, `tox -e docs` will install Pyramid into a virtual environment, then build its docs. Check out Pyramid's [HACKING.txt](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/HACKING.txt) and [tox.ini](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/tox.ini) for more example usage and configuration.